# Mobile devices getting external ip on wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

I have the following network configuration (I've simplified the network for pratical means): A cable modem with 2 wireless routers on cascade, sharing the same dhcp server (from router #1).

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpTiP.png)

When my cell phone connects at Router #2 network, it gets an internal valid IP, inside the range of the dhcp server. When the same cell phone connects at Router #1, it gets an out of bounds IP, which, as i can see in the router config, it's the external IP.

The first router is cloning the MAC Address of the network interface of the cable modem, which has a built in router but, because it's very limited, was put in bridge mode.

I need to setup a single wifi network, with same SSID for both routers and connectivity between all the stations, without this issue of mobile devices getting the External IP.

Comment: You've got more than one DHCP server running.

Comment: Set router #2 to be a DHCP relay instead.